# Wamppserver 2.4 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql

I installed Wamppserver 2.4 running on Windows 7 64bit, when I tried to open mysql on cmd or on mysqlcmd from the wampp menu

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin>mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

and tried this

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin>mysql -u root -p mysql1
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I can't even get into phpmyadmin, It requires a password.

what could be the problem? I have friends that install the same installer in to their systems and they did not encounter this problem. I tried reinstalling wampp but it does not fix the problem (obviously)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it gave me this notification: " Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)"

Comment: then mark it as answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/21207521/829533

Comment: I set my config to allow password, and tried logging again at phpmyadmin and gave me this error: "#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

Comment: add this line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';` after `AllowNoPassword`'s line

Comment: and try loggin with user: root, and pass: root

Comment: Still gave me the same error "#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

Comment: set `AllowNoPassword` back to true and login with no password

Comment: and then change it in the way I describe in the answer

Comment: Still gave me the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own problem, on your start menu, search "services" open it and look for anything that have "mysql" on it, then stop those services, try phpmyadmin again and it should go through by now.

Answer (score 0):

For `phpmyadmin` leave the password field blank and press `go`

once you are successfully signed in you will see the link **Change password** under `General Settings` use it and setup new password

Comment: I can't even go through the phpmyadmin login page, thanks for trying to answer